# Scala: Capture stdout / stderr of interactive external process

Tags: scala, process, stdout

I'm trying to capture the stdout and stderr streams from an external process that requires user input. So far I've focused my efforts on using the tools available in the `scala.sys.process` package. I can get the user interaction *or* the stream capturing working correctly, but not both at the same time. I've added a straightforward test case that has examples of both behaviors. I suspect I'm not connecting the in/out streams correctly but I'm a little lost.

```
import scala.sys.process._

object Test extends App {
  val processLogger = ProcessLogger(
    (out: String) => println(s"OUT: $out"),
    (err: String) => println(s"ERR: $err")
  )

  val cmd = "sbt new scala/scala-seed.g8"

  // Allows user interaction but doesn't allow capture of stdout/stderr
  val exitCode1 = cmd.run(connectInput = true).exitValue() 

  // Allows stdout/stderr capture but user input prompt is not displayed
  val exitCode2 = cmd.run(processLogger, connectInput = true).exitValue() 
}
```

Comment: The 2nd attempt doesn't relay the user prompt because `ProcessLogger` IO is handled line-by-line. A user prompt that doesn't end with a new-line character isn't a full line and the `ProcessLogger` won't see it until the process provides a new-line or it terminates. Unfortunately, I'm not aware if there's any way around this.

Comment: you can use the following to execute it -->> cmd!processLogger